# Using a property to change a global variable in javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a change in a global variable in line 11 of my code on

https://github.com/bahiirwa/Accrue.js/blob/gh-pages/jquery.accrue.js

The effect I want to achieve is when I pass a property(correct the terminology if I am wrong to affect the global variable in the plugin called.)

```
<script src="jquery.accrue.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".calculator").accrue(
        currencySym: GBP,
    );
});
</script>
```

Line 11 in the jquery.accrue.js look like this

```
;(function( $, window, document, undefined ){

    var currencySym = "UGX";

    // let's start our plugin logic
    $.extend($.fn, {
        accrue: function( options ){
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what's the problem/question?

Comment: You probably meant `.accrue({
        currencySym: "GBP",
    });`

Comment: @andreas I am trying to modify this to allow for someone to pass in a dynamic value of currency unit. So far I have only got it to work at a global variable level. I need to add a property to run a dynamic currency unit without touching the plugin accrue.js file

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your currency unit as a valid object, i.e.

```
$(".calculator").accrue({
    currencySym: 'GPB'
});
```

Then you can read the option and update your variable accordingly inside the `$.extend`:

```
var currencySym = "UGX";

$.extend($.fn, {
    accrue: function (options) {
        // read currency from options object or use default (if undefined)
        currencySym = options.currencySym || currencySym;
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Simon but the solution has not worked. Something is amiss. https://github.com/jpederson/Accrue.js

@andreas  I am trying to modify this to allow for someone to pass in a dynamic value of currency unit. So far I have only got it to work at a global variable level. I need to add a property to run a dynamic currency unit without touching the plugin accrue.js file

Comment: @omukiguy well I just tried it and it works for me... but you didn't say before that you don't want to edit the `jquery.accrue.js` file. I'm not sure how you think you could achieve that. And actually you edited the file in your fork. Anyway if you want to do a fork, the correct way is to add a `currencySym` property with default value to the default options (`$.fn.accrue.options`, line 131 in jpederson's repo) and then use `options.currencySym` throughout your plugin implementation. Then you can dynamically pass `{ currencySym: 'GPB' }` as the options object when initializing the plugin.

Comment: Can you share a gist of the accrue.js file edited with your solution?

Comment: here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/h8d2mzzf/2/ I added the `currency_symbol` option (l. 132) and removed the `$` signs in `response_basic` (l. 155) and `response_compare` (l. 160). Then I changed the `formatNumber()` function (l. 168) to also accept a currency symbol argument that is used as a prefix for the returned string. then in all the `formatNumber` calls I passed `options.currency_symbol` as second input (e.g. lines 232, 234, 235, ...)

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm. I had to do some edits on line 370-373.